# Can C++ std::numeric_limits<float>::max() be accurately stored in a float and later compared?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I know that some values are unable to be easily defined in floats, and are only 'approximated', making direct 'equals' comparisons frequently not work.

Can std::numeric_limits::max be stored in a float accurately, and will this code function as expected?

```
float myFloat = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

//...later...
if(myFloat == std::numeric_limits<float>::max())
{
    //...myFloat hasn't changed...
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/LeRcUt

Comment: `max` is a function, you probably want `max()` there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given (non-NaN) `float` variable, `f`, it is guaranteed that `f == f` is always true. Since `myFloat` gets set to some `float` value, of course it will compare equal to that same value.

You are apparently thinking of cases such as:

```
float f1 = 0.1;
float f2 = 1.0/10;
assert( f1 == f2 );
```

which might fail, but this will not fail:

```
float f1 = 0.1;
float f2 = 0.1;
assert( f1 == f2 );
```

Although the value stored in the variables may not be exactly equal to `0.1` but may have a different value instead, you will get the *same* value for both variables, and so they will compare equal.

Whatever value `numeric_limits<float>::max()` happens to return, it is a fixed value that will compare equal to itself.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question.
You said, "it is guaranteed that f == f". Could you post what part of the standard? Regardless, marked as the accepted answer since it addresses the question the most directly.

Comment: Seriously?!  The standard just says `operator==` "shall yield `true` if the specified relationship is true and `false`  if it is false." **Obviously** a variable's value equals itself, because by definition it holds the same value as itself, it can't hold more than one value! (This doesn't apply to NaN values, which always return false even when compared to themselves, but NaNs are special)

Comment: But I'm not comparing it to itself. I'm comparing the result of a compiler-implemented static function returning a floating point value, to a later execution of the same function, and I've already expressed ignorance of floating-point implementations.
Yes, "varA == varA" is guaranteed to be true, but I thought your comment was "<original floating point value> == <original floating point value>" after approximations (I misread your post). Is that guaranteed by the standard?
My mistake if this is a stupid question!

Comment: `numeric_limis` isn't implemented by the compiler, it's just a library function that returns a float. If the value is _already stored in a float_ then how can its value change? every time you call the function you will get **the same value** back. If you assign that `float` value to a `float` you still have **the same value**. Even if the function returned a value that isn't exactly representable (which it doesn't) such as 0.1 then every time you call it you get **the same value**.

Comment: The second `f1==f2` example in my answer demonstrates that situation, two variables get given the same value so they have **the same value**

Comment: I understood the second example, but my follow up question is more along the lines of: **assert((1.0f/10.0f) == (1.0f/10.0f))** - does the standard guarantee that identical floating point *expressions* will always result in the same approximation of the value (assuming it's during a single execution of the program)?

Comment: Technically I think that's implementation defined, but most implementations follow IEEE 754, which says yes. Floating point operations are inexact, but not non-deterministic.

Comment: @JaminGrey In practice, you will likely find that `f==f` is always true but `complicated_expr()==complicated_expr()` is very rarely false. Many compilers, either intentionally (`gcc -ffast-math`) or accidentally, sometimes allow themselves to do floating-point math at a different precision from the requested. For example, if `f` holds `0.1`, then a not-quite-smart-enough compiler might optimize `f==f` into `f==0.1` and perform the comparison at double-precision (perhaps because that's faster on whatever target it cares most about), so it ends up being equivalent to `0.1f==0.1`, which is false.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[numeric limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/) is a class template and max is a static method:

```
  template <class T> class numeric_limits {
  public:
  ...
  static T max() throw(); //constexpr if using C++11
  ...
  };
```

So for type float you will actually be using `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` and simply comparing two floats of equal value (so long as you have not operated on myFloat prior to the comparison).  The value from max() is going to be a consistent float for your platform and will have an equivalent binary representation to itself.

The main trouble you would have is trying to serialize and deserialize across platforms with a different floating point binary representation.  So if you were to try and serialize your myFloat variable and on some other machine you try to compare the result of the deserialized value directly to numeric_limits::max():

```
if( myFloat == std::numeric_limits<float>::max() )
```

The result may no longer hold true.  You would then need to encode your concept of "MAX" in your binary representation and interpret it explicitly how you want.

Comment: Good point about the serialization - thankfully that doesn't harm my project.

Thanks for the answer. Ignoring the *differences* in representation Is it reasonably safe to assume that std::numeric_limits<float>::max() will always be accurately represented in different representations/platforms/compilers, even if each is different?

Comment: The question makes no sense. `numeric_limits<float>::max()` returns some `float` value. Whatever that value is **must** be "accurately represented" because it is already stored in a `float`! You cannot store `0.1` in a float accurately, but whatever value is returned by `numeric_limits<float>::max()` returns _is already stored in a float_, i.e. as the answer above says, it "will have an equivalent binary representation to itself"

Comment: That is definitely a reasonable assumption. All floating point representations have a maximum representable number.  If this number was fuzzy it wouldn't be representable.  floats are just binary numbers like any other under the covers simply interpreted differently based on the representation.  You can't rely much on how operations will affect the float value (unless you know the details of the representation) but you can be sure that any number is equal to itself. At the point you can inspect the return value of max it is a representable float.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good point. That's kinda what I'm trying to validate though, floating point representations isn't a subject I've truly learned.
I get what you're saying - if 0.1 happens to becomes 0.09324242 or whatever, the next time I use 0.1 it'll also become 0.09324242.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but

```
myFloat += someSmallFloat;
```

may not change the value of `myFloat`.

If you'd like to understand more, there's a great tutorial on floating point representations called [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).